# Limit as $x$ goes to the right and at the left of a point of not definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

The function $f(x)=\log(x^4-2x^2+1)+ \frac{-1}{2(x-1)}$ at the right of -1 goes to $-\infty$ and also at the left. But if I plot $f$ in geogebra it does not seem that that $f$ goes to $-\infty$ at the right and the left of -1. Why?

Answer (score 1):

That is because
$$\log(x^2-2x^2+1)=\log\bigl((x^2-1)^2\bigr),$$
and the argument of the log tends to $0^+$ in both cases

Comment: So the function goes to $-\infty$...why the graphical result does not show this?

Comment: Can you help me to understand this?

Comment: I have really no idea (I don't have geogebra on my system). Did you try with gnuplot?

Comment: What I want to say is only if the fact that the limits are $-\infty$ is right

Comment: Yes, because $\lim_{u\to 0^+} \log u=-\infty$, and precisely $(x^2-1)\to 0^+$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the logarithm is positive for $x\ne1$ and, since it goes to $0$ for $x\to-1$, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\log(x^4-2x^2+1)=-\infty
$$
(two-sided limit).

On the other hand
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{-1}{2(x-1)}=\frac{1}{4}
$$
Thus you can safely state that
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}f(x)=-\infty
$$

Note that, instead,
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\infty,\qquad \lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=-\infty
$$